# How to exclude an item from the search?

Tags: html, jquery, search

I have a search for items. The block in which the value is searched consists of several elements. I need to exclude the last item from the search. Those. so that this element is not affected, except for the rest.

I tried like this

```
$('.blog_content_item').not('.last').each(function() {...});
```

and

```
$(".blog_content_item:not('.last')").each(function() {...});
```

Does not help. Both that and that is not true on syntax. Please tell me how to exclude the "last" element from the search. Thank.

```js
$('.blog_content_item').each(function() {
  if($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) === -1) {
  ...
  return;
  } else {
  ...
         }             
});
```

```html
<div class="blog_content_item">
  <div class="first">
  <div class="middle">
  <div class="last">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

Sample HTML

```
<div class="blog_content_item">
  <div class="first">First</div>
  <div class="middle">Middle</div>
  <div class="last">Last</div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$('.blog_content_item >div:not(:last-child)').each(function () {
    // your awesome stuffs here
    console.log($(this).text());
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `:not()` filter with descendant selector

https://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/

> A descendant of an element could be a child, grandchild,
> great-grandchild, and so on, of that element.

```js
console.log($('.blog_content_item :not(.last)').get())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="blog_content_item">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="last"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Although, your answer is correct, you need to add good description. OP is also using `:not()`. How does using `:not()` the way you suggest yield correct result? Explain it in the answer.

Comment: Does not work. The "last" tag is still not excluded from the search.